# What would cause RegexKit to spawn a "Requested configuration not supported" error?

Tags: regex, regexkit

I have the framework installed per the instructions on the website and RegexKit.h imported into my AppController header file. I'm using a simple method defined in AppController.m to make sure everything is working.

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    NSString *str = @"Torpedos: 0 1 1 0 1 Lasers: 150 150";
    NSString *rgx = @"Torpedos: (([0-1x]) ){3,8}";
    NSString *torpStr = NULL;
    [str getCapturesWithRegexAndReferences:rgx, @"$0", &torpStr, nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", torpStr);
}
```

I get this error in the console when I click the Test button:

> -[NSMapTable initWithKeyPointerFunctions:valuePointerFunctions:capacity:]
>   Requested configuration not supported.

I've spent half a day searching the net and looking through the Apple Dev docs, and all I've found is a notation in the Apple docs indicating that entries must be explicitly removed if you aren't using garbage collection (which I am). And...

> When configuring map tables, note that only the options listed in
>   “NSMapTableOptions” guarantee that the rest of the API will work
>   correctly—including copying, archiving, and fast enumeration. While
>   other NSPointerFunctions options are used for certain configurations, such
>   as to hold arbitrary pointers, not all combinations of the options are valid.
>   With some combinations the map table may not work correctly, or may not
>   even be initialized correctly.

Which sounds like what could be going on. I just have no clue where to begin looking.

Answer (score 0):

So far I found out how to remove the first warning. I was getting an error regarding a missing semi colon.

"FPropertyListCreateFromXMLData(): Old-style plist parser: missing semicolon in dictionary."

http://cross-the-sea.blogspot.com/2009/07/about-alert-message-of.html

Discusses how to remove that error